# Table render error in react components 6.0.1

Tags: gooddata

I'm working on updating our @gooddata/react-components package from version 5.3.1 to version 6.0.1.  I had a number of table insights which were working fine, but now some of them fail to render with this error:

`Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of 'BubbleHoverTrigger'.`

I'm passing the same `props` as I was with 5.3.1, so why are my insights now failing to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same error and fixed it by upgrading to React 16 from React 15 I was using before. The `@gooddata/react-components` uses the new React since version 6.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Stewart, for the report.

We will investigate. Could you tell us which component is failing and what type of props are you sending? Is it saved `<Visualization />` or . It seems like a missing test at our side. Our automated tests usually catch these.

Comment: Hi, Tom.  We are creating creating Table components programmatically using React-Dom, following the documentation here: https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/table_component.html

Unfortunately there isn't enough room in the comments to post the entire props.  Is there another way I can provide them to you?

Answer (score 1):

Stewart, you can definitely provide it through opening an issue on the GitHub repository if here isn't room in the comments: https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-react-components

Comment: Thanks Jarda.  I filed an issue for this here: https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-react-components/issues/644